How do I have my setting for "Holdout" on one object but not another?
I'm relatively new and I'm working on a cup spilling animation. I have a back plane with my video on it, with then my cup and liquid in front of it.

And now here it is from the viewport rendered camera view.

The problem I'm having is with my cup. In this rendered view, the whole animation looks completely fine. However, when I go to actually render it, the cup is cut-out from the plane behind it, creating a mask in the video that looks like this (same exact setup as previous picture, just rendered).

Is there any way to to cut that part of liquid out of frame while keeping my back video, or is that only possible with masking/compositing? By the way, I also used "Background Images" in the camera, which is what filled in the mask in the rendered camera view. Thanks in advance.

A background image in the camera will not be visible in the real render, so it doesn't fill up the holdout. How is your compositing set up, you're not showing it in the question? You have to alpha over the render over the original footage.

You need to composite the rendered image with the backplate video with an Alpha Over node. Use the compositor workspace

Ok thank you guys. I know absolutely nothing about compositing, and was wondering if I would be able to achieve this without it. I don't know the rules here, but since you guys technically answered my question do I have to do something?

I ended up compositing using the start of this video https://youtu.be/Kw-RRyAXumc?si=YlA3GUcJ1BXjQpFS. Then it worked like I wanted it to.
